# history across sessions in ipython using python-mode.el in emacs

Tags: emacs, ipython, python-mode

How would I save history across sessions in ipython using python-mode.el in emacs. To be sure this feature works when I run ipython at the command prompt rather than from within emacs 
Thanks.

python-mode 6.2.1+

ipython 1.2.1

emacs 24.3.1

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it's broken currently. Your bug report resp. feature request is welcome at https://gitlab.com/python-mode-devs/python-mode/issues